# Dimension too large while plotting external graphic

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a plot using an external graphic. The problem is that the axis extents are very different, so I need to use the unit vector (1,300). When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x 
l.23 \end{axis}
```

How can I convince pgfplots to do the job without manually fiddling with the scaling and the y tick labels?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  enlargelimits=false,
  axis on top,
  xlabel={$y$},
  ylabel={$x$},
  unit vector ratio*=1 300,
  width=15cm,
  tick align=outside,
  x dir=reverse,
]
\addplot graphics [xmin=5,xmax=-5,ymin=33.119,ymax=33.124] {img.png};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the file img.png:
[image: img.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust `height` instead of `unit vector ratio`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  enlargelimits=false,
  axis on top,
  xlabel={$y$},
  ylabel={$x$},
  %unit vector ratio*=1 300,
  width=15cm,
  height=3cm,
  tick align=outside,
  ytick=\empty,   %% y tick doesn't make sense for such a graph
  x dir=reverse,
]
\addplot graphics [xmin=5,xmax=-5,ymin=33.119,ymax=33.124] {img.png};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But don't the height / width values include axes, labels and so forth? So how do I set the aspect ratio of just the plot area?

Comment: Hmm, well I guess the precise aspect ratio is not that important in my application, so I'm gonna accept the answer. It would be interesting, though, to see if there is another solution?